# How can I map the sample from the original feature space to the new kernel feature space? (Sk-learn)

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

Let's say I have a very basic SVM model, implementin sk-learn:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight=weights, gamma=gamma)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

X is the sample space with 2 features.
I plot these sample using a scatter plot:
[image]

And plot the hyperplane:
[image]
But now, I want to see how the new kernel (from radial basis function) transforms my sample into a 3D space, how would I do that?

I'm more interested in getting the new set of 3D coordinates After that, plotting in 3D is not that difficult.

Thanks!

Comment: You do know that SVMs don't actually transform the input into a higher dimension using the kernel trick? If I were you, I'd just implement the `rbf` as a function and pass my input to it and then plot the new transformation.

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi I did not know that! Can you elaborate further? I'm still learning here.

Comment: Well what I tried to explain was, when you have data that cannot be separated by a linear boundary, an SVM, will use a kernel trick such as the `rbf` kernel to "project" the data into a higher dimensional space where it becomes linearly separable. So what you want is to plot the `rbf` kernel projection to see how the new data looks like. The problem you might encounter is that the `rbf` kernel might project it in 3rd, 4th, or nth dimension. You can only make use of 3rd. Play around with that idea.